# How to get form data after redirecting to another subdomain and get back to same url?

Tags: struts2

I am using Struts2.

I have a payment page for e.g. `abc.example.com` and need to redirect to some common url like `payment.example.com`. Here user redirect to common payment page then user select particular payment gateway, after doing payment user gets back to this URL.

The problem here I am facing is that how to maintain User's data i.e. URL, amount to be paid and other information.

Answer (score 2):

If you redirect your user's data to somewhat domain other than your application domain you are loosing it. Before you redirect it you should save data somewhere in the persistent context, cookies or database, so when you called back you can retrieve that data from the context and reuse it in the upcoming request.